# How to use a previous list in another expression

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am trying to use the list created for Mf_values to be used in the expression for P0 in my code. I have tried it in the following way:

```
Mf_values=[0.8, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5]
Vinf_values=[Mf_value*(gamma*R*tatm)**0.5 for Mf_value in Mf_values]
print(Vinf_values)
P0=[(1+((gamma-1)/2)*(Mf_values**2)**(gamma/(gamma-1))]
T0=(1+((gamma-1)/2)*(Mf_values**2))*tatm
```

I want to use the 4 different Mf_values for solving the expression for P0 and T0 and save the results in a list in a similar fashion to Vinf_values. However, python gives me the following error:

```
P0=[(1+((gamma-1)/2)*(Mf_values**2)**(gamma/(gamma-1))]
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Use numpy (arrays) for this kind of calculations; standard python lists are not meant to be used like that.

Comment: You have mismatched parentheses in your expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to do what you want using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

# Change the below values to the correct ones
gamma = 0.5
R = 1.0
tatm = 1.0

Mf_values = np.array([0.8, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5])
Vinf_values = Mf_values * (gamma * R * tatm)**0.5
print(Vinf_values)
P0 = (1 + ((gamma - 1) / 2) * (Mf_values**2))**(gamma/(gamma - 1))
T0 = (1 + ((gamma - 1) / 2) * (Mf_values**2)) * tatm
```

If really need lists, you can simply convert to lists by doing this:

```
P0 = list(P0)
T0 = list(T0)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Suppose I wanted to create a range for my Mf_values as follows: Mf_values = np.arange(0.8,0.01,1.5).  How could I convert this range into an array?

Comment: Yes I agree, but I want to my range of Mf_values to be from 0.8 to 1.5 each time incrementing by 0.01. I thought it would be easier to use np.arange but it doesn't work.

Comment: Then it should be np.arange(0.8, 1.51, 0.01), if you want to include 1.50. The step size should be last. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Answer (score -1):

you cannot do `pow` operation and other operations that you're trying to do with a normal python list, you can either use [numpy](https://www.numpy.org/) or you can do the following :

```py
Mf_values = [0.8, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5]

Vinf_values = [ Mf_value * ( gamma * R * tatm ) ** 0.5 for Mf_value in Mf_values ]

Mf_values_2 = [v ** 2 for v in Mf_values ]

tmp = [ v ** ( gamma / (gamma - 1) ) for v in Mf_values_2 ]

P0=[ v * (1 + ( ( gamma - 1 ) / 2)) for v in tmp]

tmp2 = [ v * (1 +  ( (gamma - 1) / 2 )) for v in Mf_values_2 ]

T0 = [tatm * v for v in tmp2 ]
```

to do an add operation between a value and a list, do :

```py
# lst is a list and val is an number
result = [val * elem for elem in lst]
```

to do an add operation between the elements of 2 lists, do :

```py
# lst1 and lst2 are lists
result = [a + b for a, b in zip(lst1, lst2)]
```